# Convert a .sh file to a .bat file with java environment

Tags: java, linux, batch-file, converters, sh

I need to run this .sh linux bash script on windows, how can i convert it to a batch script?

Here is the code i want to convert:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIB_PATH=./lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar:./lib/backport-util-concurrent-3.0.jar:./lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:./lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/hibernate-annotations.jar:./lib/log4j-1.2.11.jar:./lib/asm-3.1.jar:./lib/c3p0-0.9.1.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/db.jar:./lib/:./lib/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar:./lib/mina-core-1.1.7.jar:./lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:./lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/asm-analysis-3.1.jar:./lib/cglib-2.2.jar:./lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:./lib/javasoft-collection.jar:./lib/commons-primitives-1.0.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar:./lib/asm-commons-3.1.jar:./lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar:./lib/jetty-6.1.19.jar:./lib/jetty-util-6.1.19.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/editor.jar:./lib/javasoft-core.jar:./lib/commonnet.jar:./lib/asm-tree-3.1.jar:./lib/commons-configuration-1.5.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/ejb3-persistence.jar:./lib/jdom.jar:./lib/paradisevm.jar:./lib/asm-util-3.1.jar:./lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar:./lib/je-3.3.75.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/hibernate3.jar:./lib/jta.jar:./lib/slf4j-jdk14.jar:./lib/xerces-2.6.2.jar:./lib/xml-apis.jar:./lib/workshop.jar:./lib/commons-math-1.2.jar:./lib/ehcache-1.5.0.jar
LIB_PATH=$LIB_PATH:./lib/promptbubble_dep.jar
/usr/bin/java -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -verbose:gc -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=31 -Djava.awt.headless=true -classpath "./lib/peony.jar:$CLASSPATH:.:$LIB_PATH" peony.game.Server $@>> stdout.log 2>&1 &
echo $! > world.pid
tail -f ./logs/world/world.log
```

Comment: We are not a code translation service

Comment: `set LIB_PATH=.....` Will solve 1/2 your problem. Changing all `/` chars to '\' chars is your other major problem.Also, no `tail` cmd in the .bat environment without installing cygwin or something else (maybe that has changed). Good luck.

Comment: Please post your answer so that others who have the same/similar question can benefit.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo off
set jar_lib=.\lib\antlr-2.7.6.jar;.\lib\backport-util-concurrent-3.0.jar;.\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;.\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\hibernate-annotations.jar;.\lib\log4j-1.2.11.jar;.\lib\asm-3.1.jar;.\lib\c3p0-0.9.1.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\db.jar;.\lib\;.\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations.jar;.\lib\mina-core-1.1.7.jar;.\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;.\lib\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\asm-analysis-3.1.jar;.\lib\cglib-2.2.jar;.\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;.\lib\javasoft-collection.jar;.\lib\commons-primitives-1.0.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;.\lib\asm-commons-3.1.jar;.\lib\commons-collections-3.2.jar;.\lib\jetty-6.1.19.jar;.\lib\jetty-util-6.1.19.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\editor.jar;.\lib\javasoft-core.jar;.\lib\commonnet.jar;.\lib\asm-tree-3.1.jar;.\lib\commons-configuration-1.5.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\ejb3-persistence.jar;.\lib\jdom.jar;.\lib\paradisevm.jar;.\lib\asm-util-3.1.jar;.\lib\commons-lang-2.3.jar;.\lib\je-3.3.75.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\hibernate3.jar;.\lib\jta.jar;.\lib\slf4j-jdk14.jar;.\lib\xerces-2.6.2.jar;.\lib\xml-apis.jar;.\lib\workshop.jar;.\lib\commons-math-1.2.jar;.\lib\ehcache-1.5.0.jar
set jar_lib=%jar_lib%;.\lib\promptbubble_dep.jar

java -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -verbose:gc -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps  -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=80 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -classpath %jar_lib%;peony.jar peony.game.Server
pause
```

Comment: pluse-uno for solving your own problem. Good luck and keep posting!